# SELECT * from multiple databases and excluding one column from the result

Tags: sql-server

As mentioned I have 3 databases (or more), and I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[FeatureVector] f, [dbo].[Defect] d,[dbo].DefectClass c
WHERE f.DefectID = d.DefectID 
  AND f.DefectMapID = d.DefectMapID 
  AND d.GaugeID = d.GaugeID 
  AND d.DefectStatus = 5 
  AND c.ClassID = d.ClassID 
  AND f.Feature0 IS NOT NULL
```

I want to exclude from the result one column say XY from the result, I've tried:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT "XY"
...
```

and

```
SELECT * DROP "XY"
...
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: And [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: copy paste all columns in excel and use transpose

Comment: what about `select * into newTable from existtable` then `alter table newtable drop column colname` finally `select * from newtable`, is it solved your issue ?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader - You suggest copying THE ENTIRE TABLE to avoid writing out the column list? My god

Comment: @Milney we can use Temp table instead of physical table.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader how is copying it to a temp table better than a persistent table. The one and only logical way to solve this "issue" is to name the columns, which should be done in every query anyway.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader - This is still a potentially massive (imagine 1,000,000 row table) performance hit, just so you can be lazy and avoid typing all columns (Which I mentioned an easy way to do, so this isn't even hard/time consuming). SQL server and the hardware is uses are expensive, you shouldn't be wasting performance just because you are lazy... Using a temp or physical table for this is a horribly inefficient idea and should certainly not be recommended (especially since you claim you are a SENIOR developer in your profile!)

Comment: @Thegameiswar - What does transpose have to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the columns explicitly instead of using *? This is best practice anyway... you really shouldn't use * anywhere as it makes your code brittle

Comment: so do SELECT * FROM sys.columns and then copy and paste them!

Comment: Sadly there is not an easier way to do this - and as I mentioned you should really explicitly state them all ANYWAY, for a number of other reasons...

Comment: You can drag the 'Columns' node from Object explorer in SSMS into a query window and it will give you the column seperated column list automatically. But I would really consider splitting your table up into smaller ones, because a 600 column (very wide) table will be very bad performance wise... Look up Extents and rows in SQL Internals, this will lead to bad performance

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in which you can explicitly specify column names and then use that view in your SELECT query.

Also this is bad practice to use tables as comma separated in SELECT query , you should be using standard JOIN instead.